# Create noise texture and set its influence rgb value?

Tags: python, texturing

I want to create a texture of type 'noise' and modify its influence rgb value. Doing this in Blender, I see the following in the info window:

```
bpy.ops.texture.new()
bpy.data.textures["Texture"].type = 'NOISE'
bpy.context.object.active_material.texture_slots[0].color =
    (0.676377, 1, 0.268503)
```

Trying to translate this to a python script:

```
myTexture = bpy.data.textures.new("myTexture", type="NOISE");

myMaterial = bpy.data.materials.new(name="myMaterial");
myMaterial.diffuse_color = (1, 1, 1);
myMaterial.texture_slots[0].color = (0.45778, 1, 0.223341);
```

the last line fails:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'color'
```

What's the right way to do this? Here's a screenshot of the blender UI, I have a new texture selected, and I'm modifying the rgb box at the bottom:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some sample code for creating a new material, texture slot, texture and setting it all up together as specified in your question:

```
m                   = bpy.data.materials.new( "MyMat" )
m.diffuse_color     = (1, 1, 1);
obj.active_material = m

ts                      = m.texture_slots.create(0)
ts.texture_coords       = 'UV' # Assuming this is what you want, could be any of the following: ('GLOBAL', 'OBJECT', 'ORCO', 'UV', 'STRAND', 'WINDOW', 'NORMAL', 'REFLECTION', 'STRESS', 'TANGENT')
ts.color                = (0.45778, 1, 0.223341)
ts.texture              = bpy.data.textures.new( "TEXTURE", "NOISE" )
```